# Are all the default applications duplicated?

Tags: applications, filesystem

I noticed that all of the default applications (Finder, Preview, etc.) each appear in `/Applications`, but also again in `/System/Applications`. Given that these applications are combined just under one GB, duplicating them all seems a massive waste of space. Neither version has an alias symbol indicating a symbolic link, but in each version (the `/Applications` and `/System/Applications`) have Last Opened dates in sync. Are the applications really duplicated in memory, or are they somehow referencing the same locations on disk from different filenames without any evidence of a symbolic link? I have heard that directories (which the applications themselves are) cannot be hardlinked so what could be going on here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those applications are not duplicated - nor are they symbolic links, hard links or firm links.

Instead what happens is that you're using Finder to view the folder - and Finder chooses to show you a mix of apps found in `/Applications` and `/System/Applications`.

For example, open Finder and navigate to `/Applications`, then try right-clicking `Photos.app` and select `Get Info`. You'll see under `Where` that Photos.app is really located in `/System/Applications`.

It is thus entirely a feature of Finder that these apps are shown together. It is not how the files are organized in the file system - so if you use other programs to list the folders (that do not implement the same special case logic as Finder), then you wouldn't find them to be duplicated.

Comment: So this is a Finder feature, not a filesystem feature. Finder is just hardcoded to show the contents of `/System/Applications` in `/Applications`. This can be further demonstrated by running `ls -la /Applications` and none of the system applications show up.

Comment: Exactly...........

Comment: This is another example of how Finder sometimes 'lies.' The others being not showing `.DS_Store`, not showing `/dev`, not showing any special inodes, etc.

Comment: They are called "firmlinks". This is relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/1490834/how-to-find-firmlinks

Comment: @Gilby No, this is not firmlinks.

Comment: Ok, but the folders are firmlinks.

Comment: @Gilby The `/System/Applications` folder is not a firmlink, no. `/Applications` is obviously a firmlink - but it is not a firmlink that involves  `/System/Applications` so it has no relevance to this question.